# How to disable wifi in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: wifi, pi-4, raspbian-buster

How to disable WiFi in Raspberry Pi4, possibly keeping the chip powered off.

Comment: Does one of the answers solve your question? It should. Please accept one to finish the question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Raspbian is managing hardware with overlays. In `/boot/overlays/README` you will find:

```
Name:   pi3-disable-wifi
Info:   Disable Pi3 onboard WiFi
Load:   dtoverlay=pi3-disable-wifi
Params: <None>
```

I suggest you just add

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-wifi
```

to `/boot/config.txt` to disable wifi. I have tested it with a Raspberry Pi 4B. It is also valid for Pi4. When disabled you will not get a WiFi interface **wlan0** as you can check with `ip -br addr`.

**UPDATE:**
*@JeffAtwood* [noted in his comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100543/how-to-disable-wifi-in-raspberry-pi-4/100549#comment166502_100549)

> They renamed it to `disable-wifi` so you can use that, `pi3-disable-wifi` was kept as a synonym for compatibility. Same thing with disabling bluetooth.

2019-10-25: seems everything is documented now in `/boot/overlays/README`.

Comment: Has anyone tested this?  I don't really want to risk bricking my pi based on an assumption :)

Comment: @Wossname I have just tested it for you and updated the answer.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks for your efforts. +1

Comment: One small tweak, they renamed it to `disable-wifi` so you can use that, `pi3-disable-wifi` was kept as a synonym for compatibility. Same thing with disabling bluetooth.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I cannot find it in the official documentation `/boot/overlays/README`. Where do you get it?

Comment: @JeffAtwood At the moment, using latest Raspbian Buster, using disable-wifi simply does not work.

Comment: @Ingo Looking in `/boot/overlays/README` from the September release of Raspbian Buster I can now see `disable-bt` and `disable-wifi` documented.

Comment: Is there a way to enable/disable this on every boot? I don't want to use Wi-Fi if Ethernet is connected.

Comment: I am using Fedora 34 server image on Raspberry 4, there you find `config.txt` under `/boot/efi`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and +1. Do you know whether this also turns off the power to the WiFi module? After all, we'd like not only the device (in the file system) to vanish, but also not be subject to radiation any more.

Answer (score 6):

Use `rfkill block wifi` and reboot to disable and `rfkill unblock wifi` and reboot to enable it again.

Answer (score 4):

Create /etc/modprobe.d/brcm-blacklist.conf with the following content:

```
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmutil
```

Reboot, and WiFi should be disabled. You may find errors in the system log depending on what method you are using to configure the network. You can choose to correct those, or not, of course.