# Raspberry PI 4B and Wifi

Tags: wifi

I am a new Pi user to the hobby.  Looking at improving wifi performance I had a question because my research hasn't revealed satisfying answers.  I have a couple USB wifi adapters. It seems necessary to disable the onboard wifi before trying one of my options to see what I get better performance out of.  In my searching I cannot find a reliable way to disable the onboard wifi other than disabling all wifi.

What would you do in my situation.  Just leave the onboard wifi running and try my other options?  Seems like a conflict would occur and cause misinformation on wifi speeds.

Thanks in advance for any information!

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100543/how-to-disable-wifi-in-raspberry-pi-4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable wifi in Raspberry Pi 4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100543/how-to-disable-wifi-in-raspberry-pi-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that disabling WiFi is the solution.

The on-board WiFi will normally be `wlan0`, but there is a potential race condition.

I suggest you `Enable predictable network i/f names` in the `Advanced` option of `raspi_config`.

Your other interfaces will then have names like `wlx00c140123456`

You can then add `denyinterfaces wlan0` to the end of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to prevent `wlan0` from getting initialised. Your other interface should be configured automatically.

See **Prevent dhcpcd from configuring an interface** and **Predictable Network Interface Names** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)